# Handlebar template using each

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

i want to display only first tr with id="firstTr-1" but it should get the data from the same object and other tr should have datas except the first one.should i add any registryhelper or is thier an inbuilt helper method!! I checked out the documentation but couldnt figure it out.

Template:

```
        <script id="firsttemp" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
        <tr id="firstTr-1">

        <td class="tableFirstCol"><input type="checkbox" class="check" id="childcheck" /></td>
        <td class="tableFirstCol"><input type="checkbox" class="star" id="childstar" /></td>
        <td class="tableFirstCol"><input type="checkbox" class="alarm" id="childalarm" /></td>
        <td class="tableFirstCol">Hero Honda<span>Hero Honda</span></td>

        </tr>
        {{#each objects}}
        <tr>

        <td class="tableFirstCol"><input type="checkbox" class="check" id="childcheck" /></td>
        <td class="tableFirstCol"><input type="checkbox" class="star" id="childstar" /></td>
        <td class="tableFirstCol"><input type="checkbox" class="alarm" id="childalarm" /></td>
        <td class="tableFirstCol">{{name}}<span>{{name}}</span></td>

        </tr>{{/each}}
</script>
```

Json:

```
var company= [

        {
        "name": "Hero Honda",
        "lastprice": 310.2,
        "dayschange": 20.1,
        "dayshigh": 220.9,
        "volume": 140.3,
        "52weekhigh": 200.3,
        "name2": "herohonda",
        "dataset": [1200,3000,3200],
        "lastprice2": "1:10pm",
        "dayschange2": "8%",
        "dayshigh2": "1.5%",
        "volume2": "1:10 Pm",
        "52weekhigh2": "1:10 Pm"
        },
        {
        "name": "Hero Honda",
        "lastprice": 310.2,
        "dayschange": 20.1,
        "dayshigh": 220.9,
        "volume": 140.3,
        "52weekhigh": 200.3,
        "name2": "herohonda",
        "dataset": [3200,3500,5000],
        "lastprice2": "1:10pm",
        "dayschange2": "8%",
        "dayshigh2": "1.5%",
        "volume2": "1:10 Pm",
        "52weekhigh2": "1:10 Pm"
        }]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're overcomplicating things. Handlebars prefers that you apply your logic to the data before Handlebars sees it. So, rather than messing around with a custom helper that will probably only be used in one place, alter your data and mark the first one with a boolean flag so that you can do a simple `{{#if _first}}` check in your template.

The template would look like this:

```
<script id="firsttemp" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    {{#each objects}}
        <tr{{#if _first}} id="firstTr-1"{{/if}}>
            <!--...-->
        </tr>
    {{/each}}
</script>
```

and you could set the `_first` flags like this:

```
company[0]._first = true;
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/3Cq9K/

---

Once you get that out of the way, you have another problem on your hands: you're duplicating the `id` attributes on your checkboxes but [`id` attributes must be unique](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/global-attributes.html#common.attrs.id):

> There **must** not be multiple elements in a document that have the same `id` value.

You'll need unique `id`s on each checkbox if you want to avoid various strange and confusing problems down the road.